# API call not retrieving from mongodb if inside a function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a one time use link and I'm trying to call a function that does a GET that I need to validate before rendering the password change form, but it never returns a value. I know the GET is correct because I created an angular service to test it, but not from within function call. Why is the URL not returning? Also it never returns `console.log("URL GET")` from function call

```
//URL Link that lets you change pw

app.get("/resetpassword/:id/:token", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Outputs");

  console.log(req.params.id);
  console.log(req.params.token);

  User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(user => {
    var secret = user.password + "-" + user.passwordCreated.getTime();
    var payload = jwt.decode(req.params.token, secret);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth failed"
      });
    }
    console.log("USER FOUND");
    console.log(user);
    fetchedUser = user;
    instagramName = user.instagramName;
    let generatedUrl =
      "http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/" +
      payload.id +
      "/" +
      req.params.token;
      console.log("Before function")
     CheckIfUrlExists(generatedUrl);
     console.log("after function")

    res.send(
      '<form action="/resetpassword" method="POST">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' +
        payload.id +
        '" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' +
        req.params.token +
        '" />' +
        '<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your new password..." />' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />' +
        "</form>"
    );

  });
});

function CheckIfUrlExists(urlValue) {
  app.get("/api/urls", function(req, res) {
    console.log(res);

    Url.findOne({ url: urlValue }).then(url => {
      console.log("URL GET Request");
      console.log(url);
      if(url){
        res.send("link has expired");
        res.end();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this?

I moved the url lookup business inside the same route.

```
app.get("/resetpassword/:id/:token", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Outputs");

  console.log(req.params.id);
  console.log(req.params.token);

  User.findById(req.params.id).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth failed"
      });
    }

    var secret = user.password + "-" + user.passwordCreated.getTime();
    var payload = jwt.decode(req.params.token, secret);

    console.log("USER FOUND: ", user);

    let generatedUrl = `http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/${payload.id}/${req.params.token}`;

    Url.findOne({ url: generatedUrl }).then(url => {
      console.log("URL GET Request: ", url);
      console.log(url);
      if (url) {
        res.send("link has expired");
        res.end();
      } else {
        res.send(
          '<form action="/resetpassword" method="POST">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' +
            payload.id +
            '" />' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' +
            req.params.token +
            '" />' +
            '<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your new password..." />' +
            '<input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />' +
            "</form>"
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function called `CheckIfUrlExists` doesn't actually check if a URL exists. It registers a handler for the URL `/api/urls` which, when invoked, will check the URL passed as `urlValue`. If the function is only supposed to check the URL, it should not be doing `app.get`.

Comment: I took out the app.get and I'm just using Url.findOne. It seems to be working now. Thanks!